# passing multiple arguments in rename_all()

Tags: r, dplyr

To tidy up column names, is there a way to pass multiple arguments in `rename_all()`?

**Example**: I'd like to cleaning up the following column names by changing them all to lower, removing the `.`, and replacing the spaces with `_` using `rename_all()`

```
> colnames(tibble("COLUMN 1." = (1:3), "column 2." = (1:3)))
[1] "COLUMN 1." "column 2."
```

And I can do it as follows:

```
> tibble("COLUMN 1." = (1:3), "column 2." = (1:3)) %>% 
+     rename_all(tolower) %>% 
+     rename_all(~gsub("\\ ", "_", .x)) %>% 
+     rename_all(~gsub("\\.", "", .x))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  column_1 column_2
     <int>    <int>
1        1        1
2        2        2
3        3        3
```

But is there a way to do this with one call of `rename_all()` instead of 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also be able to do it with pipe *within* the `rename_all()` call:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble("COLUMN 1." = (1:3), "column 2." = (1:3)) %>% 
  rename_all(~ tolower(.) %>% str_remove(., '\\.') %>% str_replace(., ' ', '_'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! For anyone using it to remove/replace more than one instance of a character, be sure to change `str_remove` to `str_remove_all` and `str_replace` to `str_replace_all`

Comment: Yeah, good point, `str_remove()` and `str_extract()` will only affect the first match it finds!

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `gsub` with `chartr`

```
tibble::tibble("COLUMN 1." = (1:3), "column 2." = (1:3)) %>%
       dplyr::rename_all(~gsub("\\.", "", chartr(" ", "_", tolower(.x))))

#  column_1 column_2
#     <int>    <int>
#1        1        1
#2        2        2
#3        3        3
```

---

Or we can use `mgsub` which as the name suggests uses multiple `gsub`

```
tibble::tibble("COLUMN 1." = (1:3), "column 2." = (1:3)) %>%
   dplyr::rename_all(~mgsub::mgsub(tolower(.), c('\\.', ' '), c('', '_')))
```